# Confused with size of long and double

Tags: java, memory-management

Looking at Java (but probably similar or the same in other languages), a long and a double both use 8 bytes to store a value.

A long uses 8 bytes to store long integers from -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

A double uses 8 bytes to store double-precision, floating-point numbers from -1.7E308 to 1.7E308 with up to 16 significant digits.

My question is, if both use the same number of bytes (8 bytes or 2^64), how can double store a much longer number? 1.7E308 is a hell of a lot larger than 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

Comment: It can do so with loss of precision. Read http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Comment: Because you can add 1 to any long but you cannot add 1.0 to some doubles such as 1.6E308. Or, if you want to be able to add 0.00000000001 then your double number cannot go over 1.0 which is incredibly smaller than the long.

Comment: A floating point number is stored in the computer equivalent of exponential notation (kind of like "1.234E56" only in binary).  The `int` or `long` value, on the other hand, is stored in the computer equivalent of ordinary numbers (eg, 12345678, with no decimal point and no exponent).  The *range* of float/double numbers is larger but the *precision* is less.

Comment: As I researched, Java double can store a 15 digit effective decimal digits. However a long number can reach up to 19 digits(922,...). So, the question should be "How 15 digit capacity can contain 19 digits." So, the last statement of https://stackoverflow.com/users/2662723/user2662723 is confusing.

Answer (score 7):

The absolute quantity of information that you can store in 64 bit is of course the same.

What changes is the meaning you assign to the bits.

In an `integer` or `long` variable, the codification used is the same you use for decimal numbers in your normal life, with the exception of the fact that number two complement is used, but this doesn't change that much, since it's only a trick to gain an additional number (while storing just one zero instead that a positive and a negative).

In a float or double variable, bits are split in two kinds: the mantissa and the exponent. This means that every double number is shaped like `XXXXYYYYY` where it's numerical value is something like `XXXX*2^YYYY`. Basically you decide to encode them in a different way, what you obtain is that you have the same amount of values but they are distribuited in a different way over the whole set of real numbers.

The fact that the largest/smallest value of a floating number is larger/smaller of the largest/smalles value of a integer number doesn't imply anything on the amount of data effectively stored.

Answer (score 2):

A double can store a larger number by having larger intervals between the numbers it can store, essentially. Not every integer in the range of a double is representable by that double.

More specifically, a double has one bit (S) to store sign, 11 bits to store an exponent E, and 52 bits of precision, in what is called the mantissa (M).

For most numbers (There are some special cases), a double stores the number (-1)^S * (1 + (M * 2^{-52})) * 2^{E - 1023}, and as such, when E is large, changing M by one will make a much larger change in the size of the resulting number than one. These large gaps are what give doubles a larger range than longs.

Answer (score 0):

Long or int are signed entities which can be positive or negative but never have any decimal part.

Float or double types are used in computers to represent numbers having decimal parts.

Both long and double are 64 bits. 
Long has 1 bit for signed (to determine positive or negative), and the rest 63 bits make up the number. So there range can be -2^63 to 2^63-1

Doubles are represented as in a different way specified by IEEE Standard for Binary Floating-Point Arithmetic, devised to store very large numbers in computers.
64 bits of double represented as -  [1 bit][11 bits exponent][52 bit mantissa]

**Lets see this with an example to convert say 100.25 into binary form stored as double**

1. Decimal 100.25 converted into binary is 1100100.01
2. Binary 1100100.01 is then normalized as 1.10010001 * 2^6
3. 6 is the exponent component. We select base or offset to be 1023 to it so that both negative and positive can be represented properly. So 6+1023=1029 is the offsetted exponent component after adding bias. 100000011 is the binary representaion of exponent.
4. To calculate Mantissa from 1.10010001, we ignore 1 that is present towards the right of decimal and just use all the number(i.e. 10010001) to the right of the decimal and right padd any remaining 52 bits with zero.
   So, now mantissa will be 1001 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
5. So, finally the 64 bits are represented as
   signed bit    exponenet    mantissa
    0          100000011   1001 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000

Answer (score 0):

Reading [Delimanolis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis) statement above, I tested a loss of precision in long-to-double conversion - an integral value as big as 500 is ignored(see below).

```
long L;
double D;

L = 922_3372_0368_5477_5807L;
L -= 500;
D = L;
L = (long)D;

System.out.println("D and L: " + D + " " + L);
```

---

### output

```
D and L: 9.223372036854776E18 9223372036854775807
```